# Correct way to test methods that may return exceptions

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-2.0

I'm testing a `User::validateAdmin()` model method that can do three things:

- If valid admin, return `true`
- If expired admin, return `false`
- If not an admint, throw `NotAnAdminException`

So far I have this:

```
$result = $this->User->validateAdmin($validAdmin);
$espected = true;
$this->assertEquals($result, $espected);

$result = $this->User->validateAdmin($disabledAdmin);
$espected = false;
$this->assertEquals($result, $espected);

$this->setExpectedException('NotAnAdminException');
$result = $this->User->validateAdmin($anotherUserRole);
$espected = null;
$this->assertEquals($result, $espected);
$this->setExpectedException(null);
```

... but this makes PHPUnit ignore all subsequent `NotAnAdminException` usages, either expected or not.

What's the correct to properly test my three scenarios?

Comment: It looks like you have put that all in a single test?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561908/phpunit-doesnt-continue-test-after-expecting-an-exception ?

Comment: Yeah, put the stuff that throws exceptions into a single test case method and assert via doc block annotations.

Comment: @ndm - Thanks for the link, it clearly explains why my approach is wrong. I understand I need to either try/catch myself or split test code into different methods (no idea if there's a preferred way or it's just a matter of preference).

Comment: @mark - I think that will only test the first assertion in each test method, won't it? Additionally, I need to make tests fail if the exception is not thrown when it should.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario your test tests multiple things. You are going to make it a lot easier for yourself, the future you and everbody else having to work with the test to only test a single thing in a test.

Comment: @PeeHaa - I've taken your advice into account though at first sight it looks messy to write a dozen test methods just to test the same function with different data sets (and CakePHP core builtin tests actually group related assertions). So far, I think I got my current question answered and I've composed a (hopefully correct) proper answer to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [PHPUnit doesn't continue test after expecting an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561908/phpunit-doesnt-continue-test-after-expecting-an-exception) explains, the approach shown in the question is flawed because PHPUnit wraps the test in a regular try/catch block, so as soon as an exception is thrown the rest of the assertions in the test method are ignored. Other than that, the `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::setExpectedException` method works as expected: test passes if and only if the given exception is thrown.

The cleanest approach would be to split assertions in different methods:

```
public function testvalidateAdminValid(){
    $validAdmin = ........;
    $result = $this->User->validateAdmin($validAdmin);
    $espected = true;
    $this->assertEquals($result, $espected);
}

public function testvalidateAdminExpired(){
    $disabledAdmin = ........;
    $result = $this->User->validateAdmin($disabledAdmin);
    $espected = false;
    $this->assertEquals($result, $espected);
}

public function testvalidateAdminNotAnAdmin(){
    $anotherUserRole = ........;
    $this->setExpectedException('NotAnAdminException');
    $this->User->validateAdmin($anotherUserRole);
}
```

If you prefer to stick all related tests into the same method, you have to emulate `setExpectedException` yourself, e.g.:

```
try{
    $result = $this->User->validateAdmin($anotherUserRole);
    $this->fail('Failed to throw NotAnAdminException');
}catch(NotAnAdminException $e){
    $this->assertEmpty($result);
}
```

Comment: Or simply use the doc block annotation style `@expectedException`.

Answer (score 2):

You should keep your tests short and clean. So you should definitely split your test into multiple tests that test different aspects of your method.

I also encourage you to write tests in [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) style. So you should test expected behavior e.g.:

```
public function shouldReturnTrueForAdmin() {
    //given
    $validAdmin = ........;

    //when
    $result = $this->User->validateAdmin($validAdmin);

    //then
    $this->assertTrue($result);
}
```

Testing exceptions in this style is difficult in PhpUnit.

You can try [CatchException](http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/documentation/tests.html#exception-assertions) from [ouzo goodies](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies):

```
public function shouldFailIfNotAdmin() {
    //given
    $anotherUserRole = ........;

    //when
    CatchException::when($this->User)>validateAdmin($anotherUserRole);

    //then
    CatchException::assertThat()->isInstanceOf("NotAnAdminException");
}
```