# how to send methods as lambda expressions to moq.setup

Tags: moq

My objective is to be able keep the setup method at just one place instead of all my test classes.I want to construct a lamda expression  and send it to the set up method directly.
However I can only send 2 types of lamda expressions to setup, 
without any return type, or just return type no parameters.
Is there any way around this?
If I did the below example setup doesnt let the program compile.

```
       Mock<Message> mock = new Mock<Message>();
        ParameterExpression instance =
            Expression.Parameter(typeof(Message), "i");
        ParameterExpression param =
            Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "str");
                  Expression methodCall =
            Expression.Call(instance, typeof(Message).GetMethod("gettime"),param);
        var lambda =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<Message,string,string>>(methodCall, instance,param);
```

the Message class would look something like.

```
     public class Message
    {

        public virtual string gettime (string str)
        {
            return str + DateTime.Now.ToString();

        }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest not using this kind of complicated code in unit tests. They are supposed to be simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Ufuk is right, you should shoot for simple tests. You are doing it wrong if you have this much complexity. Some options based off of what I believe to be your goal:

- Use a base class that all tests inherit from
- Use a helper method
- Allow for the duplication. Tests should be [damp not dry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453235/what-does-damp-not-dry-mean-when-talking-about-unit-tests)