# Integration Testing of similar crud resources

Tags: unit-testing, rest, integration-testing

Lets say we have a crud rest application with multiple entities and we're thinking about doing integration tests.

All these crud endpoints inherit from the same abstract crud class.
What is the best way of doing integration tests for these routes.

## Test of Abstract CRUD Class and do Integration Tests of all api routes which differ from default crud operations

- dry (no need to duplicate tests for the already tested abstract crud route
- not really an integration tests (real crud methods are never tested)

As this is not a real integration test, it is possible to miss some errors which render the api endpoint in an erroneous state

## Write generic test function to test all crud routes

- dry (just execute something like `testDefaultCrudBehaviour('/api-endpoint/entity'`)
- but not really [DAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453235/what-does-damp-not-dry-mean-when-talking-about-unit-tests)

## Manually integration testing of all crud routes

- damp
- not dry (a lot of code duplication, a lot of noise)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, test your abstract class in detail.

1) You still need to test your subclasses to see that they are wired up to the abstract class. You may not need as much detail in your subclass tests.

2) Always write test methods that can be re-run. This regression testing process is fundamental to ensuring confidence in your future change process.

3) While DRY is an important principle in general, in testing, you do have to do a lot of repetition. Proper factoring of your test code and case handling is essential for sanity, but path coverage, tested automatically as part of your regression testing, is very important.