# Rails testing - Fixtures for has_many associations

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-4, fixtures

I am new to unit testing and have a simple use case.

There are 2 models: **City**, **Resident**. A City has_many Residents.

I created 2 fixture yml files: cities.yml, residents.yml.

**residents.yml**

```
resident1:
  name: resident1

resident2:
  name: resident2

resident3:
  name: resident3
```

**cities.yml**

```
city1:
  name: city1
  residents: resident1, resident2, resident3
```

When I run a trivial test that should always pass, I get an **error**:

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'residents' in 'field list': INSERT INTO `cities` (`name`, `residents`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `id`) VALUES ('city1', 'resident1, resident2, resident3', '2014-06-09 20:42:22', '2014-06-09 20:42:22', 574963714)
```

What I **expected** is to have a City model instance with a property `name: 'city1'`, and a property `residents` an array of 3 Resident model instances.

Inside the City.rb, I specified has_many relation to the Resident model. And inside Resident.rb I specified belongs_to relation to the City model.

This should be a simple thing to do, shouldn't it?

**UPDATE #1:**

It seems it is only possible to do it by setting the city property for the Resident fixtures.

**residents.yml**

```
resident1:
  name: resident1
  city: city1 # added

resident2:
  name: resident2
  city: city1 # added

resident3:
  name: resident3
  city: city1 # added
```

**cities.yml**

```
city1:
  name: city1
  # residents: resident1, resident2, resident3
```

I guess it will have to suffice.

Comment: Fixtures are going the way of the horse and carriage with Rails. I highly recommend the Factory Girl gem, as well as this tutorial as a place to start: http://everydayrails.com/2012/03/12/testing-series-intro.html. Fixtures can cause a lot of heartache.

Answer (score 1):

I think UPDATE #1 is fine. It's how the the associations are actually stored in the DB after all, and fixtures is simply a way to seed the DB.

You could use FactoryGirl or your own code to DRY it up if you really want, but tests are supposed to be [DAMP not DRY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453235/what-does-damp-not-dry-mean-when-talking-about-unit-tests) and that extends to fixtures.