# how to test validate presence unless another field is true rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rspec, dry

Given this code:

```
field :start_now, type: Boolean, :default => true
field :time_zone
validates :time_zone, inclusion: { 
              in: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.keys 
           }, unless: :start_now?
```

I have created this rspec test, but it's long and not DRY. And the only reason to be like this is because of the "unless" condition:

```
describe "#time_zone" do
  context "scheduled" do
    before :each do
       subject.start_now = false
    end
    it { is_expected.to validate_inclusion_of(:time_zone).in_array(ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.keys) }
  end
  context "run now" do
    before :each do
       subject.start_now = true
    end
    it { is_expected.not_to validate_inclusion_of(:time_zone).in_array(ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.keys) }
  end
end
```

**Is there any shorter way to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There's really no need to make it any shorter than this.** Both tests are describing exactly what they're testing, and they're **very specific** about those tests.

From what I've seen with testing, you want your tests to be [DAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6453235/1079354).  This doesn't mean that they're not DRY, but it *does* mean that you shouldn't bend over backwards to make it as small and narrow as possible.

Your code has two distinct and mutually exclusive states, which depends on the boolean `start_now?`.  You have to test both states, and there's really no way around that.  There's no repetition either; you're testing two distinct branches.

While your contexts [could use a *wee* bit of a verbiage clean up](http://betterspecs.org/#contexts), they're pretty good at describing what it is you need to do.

Comment: thanks, this is a discussion I always have with some co-workers. Now I can  send them this link :D

Answer (score 1):

Here and improvement. Next code is more DRY and at the same time more DAMP as before:

```
describe "#time_zone" do    
  let(:validate_time_zone) { validate_inclusion_of(:time_zone).in_array(ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.keys }

  context "scheduled" do
    before :each do
       subject.start_now = false
    end
    it { is_expected.to validate_time_zone }
  end
  context "run now" do
    before :each do
       subject.start_now = true
    end
    it { is_expected.not_to validate_time_zone}
  end
end
```

Ok, so I've understand that to be DAMP (a new word for me) is good. I feel better today because I was always thinking about the problems of being too much DRY with tests and making them very difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I like to write my specs using the `let` inside of each context that is called in the external `before :each`. This avoids repeating the `before :each` for each context.

```
describe "#time_zone" do    
  let(:validate_time_zone) do
    validate_inclusion_of(:time_zone).in_array(ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.keys
  end

  before :each do
    subject.start_now = start_now
  end

  context "scheduled" do
    let(:start_now) { false }
    it { is_expected.to validate_time_zone }
  end

  context "run now" do
    let(:start_now) { true }
    it { is_expected.not_to validate_time_zone}
  end
end
```