# Execute tests declared in a trait before tests declared in test case using that trait

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, phpunit, traits

I have a Symfony `WebTestCase`-extending PHP Test class and a DRY-trait. The test functions in my class `@depend` on the test functions in my trait, however I can't manage to execute the trait tests before the class tests. Is that possible?

```
trait TestTrait
{
    /**
     * @beforeClass
     */
    public function testBeforeAnythingElseHappens()
    {
        /*...*/
    }
    /* more functions */
}
```

Test Class

```
class Test extends WebTestCase
{
    use TestTrait;

    /**
     * @depends testBeforeAnythingElseHappens
     */
    function testClassSpecificStuff()
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the trait-test-method return something. Add a parameter to the other test-method which will get the return value of the test it depends on. IIRC this enforces the dependency. See https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.test-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

First, see [PHPUnit Manual - Appendix B. Annotations](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.beforeClass):

> #### `@beforeClass`
>
> The `@beforeClass` annotation can be used to specify **static** methods that should be called before any test methods in a test class are run to set up shared fixtures.

So, you should not use `@beforeClass` here - it is intended to allow setting up fixtures. In addition, the methods annotated as such should be `static`.

Second, see [PHPUnit Manual - Appendix B. Annotations](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.depends):

> #### `@depends`
>
> PHPUnit supports the declaration of explicit dependencies between test methods. Such dependencies **do not define the order in which the test methods are to be executed** but they allow the returning of an instance of the test fixture by a producer and passing it to the dependent consumers.

So yes, you could use the `@depends` annotation to declare dependencies between tests. Just remove the `@beforeClass` annotation:

```
trait TestTrait
{
    public function testBeforeAnythingElseHappens()
    {
    }
}

class Test extends WebTestCase
{
    use TestTrait;

    /**
     * @depends testBeforeAnythingElseHappens
     */
    public function testClassSpecificStuff()
    {
    }
}
```

Third, a few words of advice (from my own experience):

- Do not require tests to be run in a certain order.
- If you arrange something in one test and need the same thing in another, just do it multiple times, do not worry too much about repeating yourself.

For reference, see:

- http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/
- [What does “DAMP not DRY” mean when talking about unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453235/what-does-damp-not-dry-mean-when-talking-about-unit-tests)