# Setting variable value on PHP ternary case

Tags: php, ternary

I am trying to use ternary output to do 2 things on the latter case.

The issue I have is setting a text value to the variable in the latter case, after incrementing the error count.

I have tried a few things, here's two attempts, but these both fail on setting the `$errors_log` value.

Q. How can i set a variable value within an output of ternary.

```
$errors_v=0;
if (validate_username() == false ? null : $errors_v++ && $errors_log='username invalid');

if ($errors_v != 0) {
    echo $errors_log;
}

function validate_username() {
    return true;
}

$errors_v=0;
$errors_log[];
if (validate_username() == false ? null : $errors_v++ && $errors_log[]='username invalid');

if ($errors_v != 0) {
    var_dump($errors_log);
}

function validate_username() {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your code must be __readable and understandable__ Currently it is not.

Comment: Care to elaborate? @u_mulder

Comment: @u_mulder is right. This is readable: `if (!validate_username()) { ... }`. Your code is harder to read, which requires extra time looking at it. Stick to these two rules, and your team mates will respect you: DRY KISS = Don't Repeat Yourself, Keep It Simple & Stupid.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs ha! i feel styoopid. Thanks. making it more difficult than it needed to be. i went with `if (validate_username()){ $v++; $errors_log='username invalid';}` and works as expected. regards >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do my ternary like below, and then check if `$errors_log` is not empty and if it's not, print out the errors.

```
$errors_log[] = validate_username() === false ? null : 'username invalid';

if (!empty($errors_log)) {
    foreach($errors_log as $error) {
        echo $error;
    }
}

function validate_username() {
    return true;
}
```

If it's needed to have a counter aswell, even though I really recommend you count on the `$errors_log` array instead, you could do something like this:

```
if (!validate_username()) {
    $errors_log[] = 'username invalid';
    $errors_v++;
}
```

Comment: @mickmackusa Hm, might be, it seemed to work fine though. Maybe I've coded too much JS, where this is possible. Ty! :)

Comment: My point is, because you are storing a null element in your shorthand conditional, foreach() will echo that null value with no visible impact on the page.

Comment: @mickmackusa True, but OP asked for a ternary according to his code.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing "longhand" and "shorthand" conditional syntax.

Your ambiguous function name coupled with its return value is confusing/unintuitive.  I recommend renaming your function or reversing the boolean it returns.

Always endeavor to use [DRY and DAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11837973/2943403) coding practices.

The approach in the second half of your code looks better than the first.
If you are going to generate an array of errors, don't bother with incrementing a counter, just count the array when you wish.

I don't see any need to fancy up your code with shorthand conditionals.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f4bfd1b5b0f93695f42cf9f6c7d3fd6cd1be318b))

```
function bad_username(){  // new meaningful function name
    return true;
}

$errors_log=[];  // declare the variable as an array
if(bad_username()){
    $errors_log[]='username invalid';  // push the value
}

if(sizeof($errors_log)){  // count elements in array, if 1 or more display them
    var_export($errors_log);
}else{
    echo "No Error";
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'username invalid',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform two operations in a ternary case. You could just check if `$errors_log` is `empty` and if it is increment `$errors_v` inside the `if` statement like this:

```
if (validate_username() == false ? null : $errors_log='username invalid');

if (!empty($errors_log)) {
   $errors_v++;
   echo $errors_log;
}

function validate_username() {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: its the '$errors_log='username invalid')' that seems not to be working

Comment: Copied and pasted my code into http://writephponline.com and output is `username invalid`. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: i require two things to happen on the latter case. set the variable value, but also increment the error count. i confirm it works without the count, but this then breaks other parts of requirement as the count is needed.

Comment: @Derple You can't set multiple values in a ternary. Then you should make a normal `if...` statement. But you shouldn't really make the count - you should just "count" on the `$errors_log` array.

Comment: yeh, i saw that, i been thinking too inside the box. i found also using `if (validate_username()){ $v++; $errors_log='username invalid';}` works great too. thanks for the help >.<

Comment: @Derple You need a `!` if you want it to make errors on a failed check :) `if(!validate_username()) ...`

Comment: Yeah it does, just choose whichever you prefer. There's never just one right answer.