# Angular base class for unit tests

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing

Is it possible to use a base class for the unit tests in angular? 
Because a lot of my imports and declarations are always the same. If i add or replace a class, i always have to change the imports and declarations in every test class.

```
    beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [DialogModule, DynamicDialogModule, FormsModule, TableModule, HttpClientTestingModule, ContextMenuModule],
        declarations: [MyDialog ,OtherDialog],
        providers: [MyService],
    })
        .compileComponents();
}));
```

The above code ist the code which is mostly the same in every test class, so this is the code that should be in the base class.

Answer (score 1):

Well yes, it's possible. You can put

```
export const configureTestBed = () => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [DialogModule, DynamicDialogModule, FormsModule, TableModule, HttpClientTestingModule, ContextMenuModule],
        declarations: [MyDialog ,OtherDialog],
        providers: [MyService],
    }).compileComponents();
```

in an exported function call it in each `beforeEach` (or something of that like).

**However**, I do not recommend this. Whenever you're unit testing, you should only `import, declare, provide` what is needed for what you are unit testing.

If you `import, declare, provide` a bunch of stuff that a `component, service, directive` does not need, you can create headaches for yourself AND it will make the tests run slower. I am speaking from experience about this.

This is a very good exchange for you to read [What does “DAMP not DRY” mean when talking about unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453235/what-does-damp-not-dry-mean-when-talking-about-unit-tests). Also, don't take it lightly, it's okay if you have some repeated code from test to test. This will give you greater flexibility and control.

Answer (score 0):

You can chuck it all in a `TestingModule`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    DialogModule, 
    DynamicDialogModule, 
    FormsModule, 
    TableModule, 
    HttpClientTestingModule, 
    ContextMenuModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyDialog,
    OtherDialog
  ],
  providers: [MyService]
})
export class TestingModule { }
```

Then in all your tests you can just import this module:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({ imports: [TestingModule] });
}))
```