# How to reduce code duplication when unit testing an HTTP request with multiple assertions in Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm using Angular's `HttpClientTestingModule` and `HttpTestingController` for mocking HTTP requests. The `login` method of my service `AuthenticationService` does two things:

1. Makes a `POST` request to the server. If the credentials are valid, the server returns a `User` object.
2. "Logs" in a user by saving the response in `localStorage`.

As a result, I want to have two tests for my `login` method:

1. Test if the user is returned
2. Test if localStorage has been set

I can include both tests in a single `it` block, but I don't want to do that. I want to have one assert per unit test.

If I split them into different tests (as shown in the example below), there is a lot of code repetition. Is there a better way to do this?

Here is the relevant section of the `authentication.service.spec.ts` file.

```
...

let authenticationService: AuthenticationService;
let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
let store = {};

// Create a mock user object for testing purposes
const mockUser: User = {
    name: 'name',
    email: 'email@example.com',
}

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [AuthenticationService],
    });
    authenticationService = TestBed.inject(AuthenticationService);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);

    // Create mock localStorage
    spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem').and.callFake(key => {
      return store[key];
    });
    spyOn(localStorage, 'setItem').and.callFake((key, value) => {
      return store[key] = value + '';
    });
    spyOn(localStorage, 'removeItem').and.callFake(key => {
      delete store[key];
    });
});

describe('login', () => {
    it('should return user', () => {
      authenticationService.login('name', 'email@example.com').subscribe(
        data => {
          expect(data).toEqual(mockUser);
        }
      )
      const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('http://example.com/login');
      expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');
      req.flush(mockUser);
    });

    it('should set localstorage', () => {
      authenticationService.login('name', 'email@example.com').subscribe(
        data => {
          expect(localStorage.getItem('theUser')).toEqual(JSON.stringify(mockUser));
        }
      )
      const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('http://example.com/login');
      expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');
      req.flush(mockUser);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      httpTestingController.verify();
    });
  });
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do both tests in one:

```
it('should return user and set localStorage', () => {
      authenticationService.login('name', 'email@example.com').subscribe(
        data => {
          expect(data).toEqual(mockUser);
          expect(localStorage.getItem('theUser')).toEqual(JSON.stringify(mockUser));
        }
      );
      const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('http://example.com/login');
      expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');
      req.flush(mockUser);
    });
```

But I see you don't want to do that. You could try creating a re-usable function (called sendLoginResponse here).

```
describe('login', () => {
    const sendLoginResponse = () => {
      const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('http://example.com/login');
      expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');
      req.flush(mockUser);
    };
    it('should return user', () => {
      authenticationService.login('name', 'email@example.com').subscribe(
        data => {
          expect(data).toEqual(mockUser);
        }
      )
      sendLoginResponse();
    });

    it('should set localstorage', () => {
      authenticationService.login('name', 'email@example.com').subscribe(
        data => {
          expect(localStorage.getItem('theUser')).toEqual(JSON.stringify(mockUser));
        }
      )
      sendLoginResponse();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      httpTestingController.verify();
    });
  });
```

Comment: Yeah, seems like there is no alternate way to do this. I'll go ahead and create a common function then as you've mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: Follow up question: Would it make sense to include `sendLoginResponse()` in `afterEach`?

Comment: That could work but to be sincere with you I like the approach of how you have it in your question. It becomes much more clearer where I can focus on one `it` block and go through the arrange, action, assert pattern rather than going through re-usable functions. This thread should be a good read for you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6453235/7365461

Comment: That thread was very insightful. Thank you so much for sharing. I was struggling with this exact issue in my unit tests and the link makes everything much clearer.