# How and should I reuse unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, dry

I have this kind of tests in most of the services I test and I'm not sure if I should reuse them by extending some base test class or by doing something else.

```
 it('should call HttpClient.get method', () => {
     // Arrange

     // Act
     callServiceWithDefaultArguments();

     // Assert
     expect(httpClient.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
```

or like this test where I test if it throws an exception with null argument

```
it('with null id should throw an exception', () => {
      // Arrange
      const exceptionMessage = new RegExp(ExceptionConstants.NULL_OR_UNDEFINED);
      id = null;

      // Act

      // Assert
      expect(() => callServiceWithDefaultArguments()).toThrowError(exceptionMessage);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't implement `DRY` for unit testing or testing code like how it is in production code because if a unit test fails I want to only look at the `beforeAll, beforeEach, afterEach, afterAll, it` blocks and understand what is failing now rather than jumping from class to class to understand what is failing.

That being said, try using `beforeAll, beforeEach, afterEach, afterAll` to keep the test code `DRY`.

A very good exchange is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11837973/7365461) on why you should favor DAMP (Descriptive and meaningful phrases) over DRY for test code.